# How to get this to work? Dockerfile FROM {YourPrivateRepo.azurecr.io/some/repo}

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, windows-server-2016

FROM microsoft/aspnet

Would like to use instead

```
FROM MyPrivateRepo.azurecr.io/some/repo
```

If this is possible how do I pass my login info?

I am very new to using Docker and Dockerfile and could not find anything on the net on how to use your own Private registry instead of Docker Hub.

I am trying to use the Azure Container registry to build my container with.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli

Since Docker Hub you can only have 1 free private repo at a time without having to upgrade and pay for it.

Currently testing out the Private Azure Container registry and works great, can push and pull my images into and out of it with no issues.

Just had not figured out how to do that in a Dockerfile or some automated task in Visual Studio Team Services.

Trying to also figure out away to reduce the amount of time it takes to build on Visual Studio Team services currently taking about 9 mins just to download the base image microsoft/aspnet.

I have a VM set up in Azure that has docker installed, is there a method to build from there remotely in Visual Studio Team services as it is already cache there and only takes a few mins to build from there locally.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I tried these two scenarios and both of them works:

1. Local machine

   - On my Linux machine, run 'docker login myregistry.azurecr.io'
   - Author Dockerfile with 'FROM: myregistry.azurecr.io/image1'
   - docker build .
     This worked fine.
2. Visual Studio Online build

   - Used docker extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docke‌​r , to build the same dockerfile in 1.
   - Configured "Build and Image" task, with myregistry.azurecr.io
   - Schedule the build on 'Hosted Linux Preview' Agent 
     It worked great. I can see in the console log that the task first executes docker login myregistry.azurecr.io and then runs the 'docker build' command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a [login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) first.

```
docker login MyPrivateRepo.azurecr.io
```

This stores the encoded credentials in `$HOME/.docker/config.json` and you can build Dockerfiles which contain references to your private repository.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, how do I put this in a Dockerfile or use on Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, that is what I am currently using to build with :)

Comment: @Kbdavis07 What's the problem with that Docker Integration extension? There is another extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lambda3.lambda3docker), also you can custom build/release task to meet your requirement. (The related tasks will be download to build agent and the source code of build/release tasks is in [agent folder]\tasks folder)

Comment: Currently even after I login into Azure repo, docker is still using the docker hub for repo instead of Azure even through it did login successfully.